# Convergence of edge eigenvalues for Gaussian matrices

Tags: random-matrices

I am reading [this lecture note](https://www.math.univ-toulouse.fr/%7Ebordenave/IMPA-RMT.pdf).
I have a difficulty in understanding the third section in chapter 6. Particularly, in **Theorem 4.1**, they claimed that

> Let $X$ be a Gaussian Wigner matrix satisfying assumptions (A). We have a.s.
> $$
> \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \lambda_1\left(\frac{X}{\sqrt{n}}\right)=-\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \lambda_n\left(\frac{X}{\sqrt{n}}\right)=2 .
> $$
> Where $\lambda_1$ is the largest eigenvalue of $\frac{X}{\sqrt{n}}$.

But in the proof, I don't understand why they said that

> Note also that Wigner semicircle law implies that a.s.
> $$
> \liminf _{n \rightarrow \infty} \lambda_1 \geq 2 \text {. }
> $$

Could you please help me by explaining that line? Thank you for your help.